# Joint and conditional singular Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I am working with singular Gaussian densities, which are formulated as follows.

Given $$x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma),\text{    }(1)$$ where $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ has rank $p <n$ and $p>0$, then one version of its probablity density function is
$$
 \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (2 \pi)^p |\Sigma|_+}} \exp{[-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^\top \Sigma^\dagger (x-\mu) ]}, \text{    }(2)
$$
where $|\bullet|_+$ denotes the product of non-zero eigenvalues of one matrix ([pseudo determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant)), and $()^\dagger$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of a matrix. See equation $(2.1)$ in [Srivastava's paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82253753.pdf).

If now I have a conditional density and a marginal density as
$$
Y| \theta \sim \mathcal{N}(A^\top\theta,\Sigma) , \text{ } \theta \sim \mathcal{N}(0,K),    \text{ 
  } (3)
$$
where $\Sigma$ is the same as in $(1)$, while $K$ is non-singular and of dimension $m$. Then the question is what is the joint density of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Y\\ \theta
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

One possible choice is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Y\\ \theta
\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma + A^\top K A &A^\top K \\
K A  & K
\end{bmatrix}). \text{    }(4)
$$
Then it can be found that the above joint density leads to the conditional density and marginal density in $(3)$, by using standard equations for **Conditional distributions** in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions).

However, the choice in $(4)$ seems to have one issue. If I use the formula that $p(Y,\theta)$ equals
$$
p(Y|\theta)p(\theta), \text{     } (5)
$$
and plug the densities into $(5)$ according to $(2)$ and $(3)$, equation $(5)$ supposes to lead to the same density as in $(4)$. However, the above equation leads to
$$
\frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (2 \pi)^{p+m} |\Sigma|_+ |K| }} 
\exp{(\cdots)}, \text{    }(6)
$$
while in general
$$
|\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma + A^\top K A &A^\top K \\
K A  & K
\end{bmatrix}|_ + \not= |\Sigma|_+ |K|,
$$
according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4047672/product-of-non-zero-eigenvalues-pseudo-determinant-of-a-singular-matrix/4048067#4048067). Therefore, there seems to be a mismatch between the joint density in $(4)$ and the one produced by $(5)$. I am not sure which one leads to the correct joint density for $\begin{bmatrix}Y \\ \theta \end{bmatrix}$, or both of them are correct due to the non-uniqueness of density functions when covariance is singular?